# SSRS - Match previous value then display something

Tags: reporting-services

Example:

Name: (a field name that display "people name")

His/her information: (match the name then pull out the field value of their "first/last name", "address
, "phone"....etc    each represent 1 field value, so it need to pull out 4 field value)

Any advice or what function to use will be appreciate.

thanks for helping!!